# how to put element between two elements

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.getElementById("div").onclick = function(ev) {
  var btn = document.getElementById("btn4");
  btn.parentNode.removeChild(btn);
  ev.target.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```css
button {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <button id="btn1">1</button>
  <button id="btn2">2</button>
  <button id="btn3">3</button>
  <button id="btn4">4</button>
</div>
```

i want to click on the white spaces between the elements to move the 4 button to its place as in clicking **between 1  2** will make the numbers **1  4  2** or clicking between 2  3 will make the numbers **2  4  3**  and if clicked **behind 3** the numbers will be **1  2  3  4** if 4 was already moved

but the number 4 is added inside the button only if clicked on buttons and nothing happens if clicked in the white spaces between

like the dragging effect to change positions

but also clicking on nearst left of a button puts it in the spaces in the left and same as right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Try the below code :

```js
document.getElementById("div").onclick = function(ev) {
var divElement = document.getElementById("div");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn4");

var oTargetInsertionElement = null;
for (var i = divElement.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var oRect = divElement.children[i].getBoundingClientRect();

    if (divElement.children[0].getBoundingClientRect().x > ev.clientX) {
        oTargetInsertionElement = divElement.children[0];            
        //alert(divElement.children[0].id + ' - Before First Element');
        break;
    } else if (divElement.children[divElement.children.length - 1].getBoundingClientRect().x < ev.clientX) {
        oTargetInsertionElement = divElement.children[divElement.children.length - 1].nextSibiling;
        //alert(divElement.children[divElement.children.length - 1].id + ' - After Last Element');
        break;
    } else if (oRect.x < ev.clientX) {
        oTargetInsertionElement = divElement.children[i + 1];
        //alert(divElement.children[i].id + '-' + divElement.children[i + 1].id);
        break;
    }
}
if (oTargetInsertionElement != btn) {
    btn.parentNode.removeChild(btn);
    divElement.insertBefore(btn, oTargetInsertionElement);
}

}
```

```css
button {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div" style="padding:10px;">
  <button id="btn1">1</button>
  <button id="btn2">2</button>
  <button id="btn3">3</button>
  <button id="btn4">4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: clicking before button 1 doesn't put button 4 at first

Comment: @JoeDoe you could handle that as a special case in the for loop

Comment: @JoeDoe - Addressed your case.. The Logic is simple The mouse Event ev.clientX < button.clientX => insert the button4 after the button

Comment: @user2932057 in **4 1 2 3** if i clicked between **1 2** i get **1 2 4 3** instead of **1 4 2 3** and same for clicking between **2 3** i get **1 2 3 4** instead of **1 2 4 3**

Comment: @JoeDoe The Button4 is moving next to the mouse cursor click position irrespective button positions.. Also, The case you have mentioned... Please fix that case alone..

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
document.getElementById("div").onclick = function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.id == "btn4") return;
  var btn = document.getElementById("btn4");
  btn.parentNode.removeChild(btn);
  ev.target.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", btn);
}
```

```css
button {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <button id="btn1">1</button>
  <button id="btn2">2</button>
  <button id="btn3">3</button>
  <button id="btn4">4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This only works if you click the buttons. He has asked to be able to click between the buttons.